# Flutter-Navigating to a screen on tapping the notification which is created using awesome notifications

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-navigation, flutter-notification, awesome-notifications

I am receiving notifications from fcm and displaying notifications using font awesome. I have the data in payload and on the basis of payload I want to navigate user to new screen. For that I am using navigator key to navigate user to the screen but receiving following error.

Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

I have 3 files main.dart ,mainScreen.dart and notificationServices.dart.
I have declared navigatorKey in main.dart and added key:navigatorKey in materialApp of mainScreen.

main.dart

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

In mainScreen.dart

```
return MaterialApp(
      key: navigatorKey,
```

When the notification is tapped a callback is called inside notificationService to navigate to new screen.
I am calling
Navigator.pushReplacement((navigatorKey?.currentContext)!,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>chatpage(Title:"Chat Name",startDate: startDate,))); in that callback function

NotificationService.dart

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement((navigatorKey?.currentContext)!,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>chatpage(Title:"Chat Name",startDate: startDate,)));
```

Is there any other method to navigate users from notification.
I also tried Get.to() navigation method but the results are same